# Why don't i get "Segmentation Fault"?

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t I get a segmentation fault when I write beyond the end of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410016/why-dont-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-write-beyond-the-end-of-an-array)

This code compiles and runs without any error. But how?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int foo[2];

    foo[8] = 4; /* How could this happen? */

    printf("%d\n", foo[8]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with **GCC 4.7.2** on Arch Linux x86_64.

```
gcc -Wall -o "main" "main.c"
```

Comment: You're just lucky the app doesn't crash.

Comment: @alk: No, a crash is the best outcome.  Really.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I somehow used the wrong wording. @EdS.

Comment: "Why don't I get a segmentation fault?" is rarely (if ever) a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because undefined behavior doesn't mean "you will receive a segfault", that would be defined behavior.

Let's assume you're running in debug mode and your compiler is padding your stack/local variable space.  You're probably just writing into some unused part of the stack space.

Build a release version on a Monday when your compiler is feeling cranky and now you overwrite the return address, or the code that sets up the call to `printf`, whatever.  Oops.

Just one possible outcome, but you get the idea.

Comment: That's the first time I've ever heard it put that way. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

`foo[8]` may be allocated for your program (padding purpose, for instance), belong to your operating system. With an undefined behavior, anything can happen; you are unlucky, because it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foo[1000000]=42;
```

and see what happens.