# Pointer access beyond allocated memory does'nt cause segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pointer-arithmetic

I'm teaching myself C,
and I do not understand why the following code do not break with a segmentation fault.

```
printf("loading \n");
conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
int rc = fread(&conn->db->max_rows,sizeof(int) , 1, conn->file);
rc = fread(&conn->db->max_data,sizeof(int) , 1, conn->file);
conn->db->rows = malloc(Get_address_size(conn) * conn->db->max_rows);
printf("address size is : %d\n", Get_address_size(conn));
int i;
struct Address * r = conn->db->rows;
for (i = 0; i < conn->db->max_rows; i++)
{
    rc = fread(&r->id, sizeof(int) , 1, conn->file);
    rc = fread(&r->set, sizeof(int) , 1, conn->file);
    r->name = malloc(conn->db->max_data);
    r->email = malloc(conn->db->max_data);
    rc = fread(r->name, conn->db->max_data , 1, conn->file);
    rc = fread(r->email, conn->db->max_data , 1, conn->file);
    r = r++;
}
r=r+100;
printf(here I'm trying to break my code %d\n",r->id);
if (rc != 1) die("Failed to load database.");
```

the Get_address_size function is just a wrapper around

```
 sizeof(struct Address)
```

Comment: What is going on here `if (rc != ) die("Failed to load database.");`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't I get a segmentation fault when I write beyond the end of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410016/why-dont-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-write-beyond-the-end-of-an-array)

Comment: @EdHeal, it just spit out a message  andexit the program with 1 (It should also free allocated memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When program starts, OS will divide the programs memory into readable (code section) and writable (data section as well as heap). Now it will depend on the address stored in the pointer you are dereferencing. If it points to a valid writable memory then no segmentation fault exception will be raised, otherwise a segmentation fault exception will be raised.