# what is difference of malloc when multiply by a number to the sizeof(data type) and without multiply by a number

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *buffer = "hello";
    char *words = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 10) {
        *(words+count) = buffer[count];
        count++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", words);
    return 0;
}
```

I am wonder what the difference of multiply a number by the `sizeof(char)` is.

For instance, if I delete the 6 (just `char *words=malloc(sizeof(char));`)
the code works, too.

I assumed it will not work however when I run it it does.

Comment: Where did you find the constant `10` ? (or `6`?) Constants don't belong in a program, if they can be derived.

Comment: 6*sizeof(char) reserves 6 chars/6 bytes in memory. You can exceed the limit though it is not safe because these addresses might be in use or can be allocated at any point...

Comment: @wildplasser I suppose it is random to show that there is no limit

Comment: When you use `malloc()`, it typically rounds up the size you request to a multiple of a convenient larger size (e.g. a multiple of 8 or even 16 bytes).  That partially protects you.  However, your code exhibits undefined behaviour by writing outside the space allocated, and by reading outside the bounds of the array `buffer` too.  Anything can happen — including that the code appears to work OK (but it isn't OK).

Comment: Your example covers only the simplest possible case: [`sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215445/2564301).

Comment: @Cedced_Bro Accessing memory past the end of an array isn't just "not safe" or "random". It's __undefined behavior__ which means the entire program doesn't have to produce reasonable results. The code is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc(6 * sizeof(char))` allocates enough memory for an array of 6 characters.

If you don't multiply by 6, you only get enough memory for 1 character. Trying to access any character other that `*words` will result in undefined behavior.

Your code is causing undefined behavior whenever `count` is more than `5`. It's writing beyond the end of `words`, and reading beyond the end of `buffer`; both of these are undefined.

Undefined behavior doesn't always produce error messages, see [Why don't I get a segmentation fault when I write beyond the end of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410016/why-dont-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-write-beyond-the-end-of-an-array). So your code may seem like it's working, but it's still wrong and could fail in the future.

Comment: The behavior is undefined *anyway*, because the code *reads* beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: No. Your answer did not mention anything about reading beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: I said "access", that means reading and writing. Anyway, I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it does not make too much sense because `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

But consider how to calculate number of bytes needed to store `n` structures of type `my_t`.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    double b;
    float x[10];
    void *y[30];
    float (*c[12])(int);
    /* more and more */
}my_t;


my_t *foo(size_t n)
{
    return malloc(n * sizeof(my_t));
}
```

It would be quite difficult to guess the size of the `struct` without using `sizeof`.

Comment: From the original question it's clear (though perhaps only if you read it) that the OP is asking about leaving off the `6`, not the `sizeof()`, so this answer (while not stating falsehood by itself) does not answer the question in a meaningful way.

Comment: @EOF what falsehood>\

Comment: No falsehood, @P__J__ — but it is not really answering the question either.