# Array dimension in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I know that arrays need to be defined with a size that cannot be modified, but in this code, the counter i exceeds the size of the array (because of the 2 in "i<sz+2" in the for loop) but the code don't give any errors, why?
another question: is it correct to use std::cin to assign the value to sz or should I assign the value of sz when I declare the variable?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sz;
    std::cin >> sz;
    int v[sz];
    std::cout << "i" << " " << "v[i]" << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<sz+2;i++){
        std::cin >> v[i];
        std::cout << i << " " << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your array isn't valid to begin with. See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: Besides that, C++ doesn't have any bounds checking for arrays. It's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure your code doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, why `std::cout << "i" << " " << "v[i]" << std::endl;` instead of the more natural `std::cout << "i v[i]" << std::endl;`?

Comment: I was focused on the size of the array, you are right...

Comment: But, if as you said "C++ doesn't have any bounds checking for arrays" and the code works fine, why is my code wrong when it exceeds the dimension?

Comment: A C++ programmer should be aware of Undefined Behavior - what it is, what it looks like, why it exists.  Your question and comments seem to be revolving around that concept.

Comment: @fabio Undefined behavior includes the possibility of "works fine" (as well as any other possibility).

Comment: @Fabio **Undefined behavior** means anything can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

Comment: For a great explanation of undefined behaviour, read Eric Lippert's answer to [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: The sad part is that std::vector (with insert) is made for this and there are very few situations where it should not be used and still variable-length arrays are being taught.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't I get a segmentation fault when I write beyond the end of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410016/why-dont-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-write-beyond-the-end-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the counter i exceeds the size of the array (because of the 2 in "i<sz+2" in the for loop) but the code don't give any errors, why?

Going out of bound of the array(as you're doing) is **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just **crash**.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

Additionally, in Standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So when you wrote:

```
int sz;
std::cin >> sz;
int v[sz]; //NOT STANDARD C++
```

The statement `int v[sz];` is not standard C++ because `sz` is not a **constant expression**.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>